# Stacking regression not initializing the estimator properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

A simple description of my machine learning pipeline:

1. Dataframe has field that identifies which city the row belongs to
2. Factory function initiates a random forest pipeline
3. Custom stacking regressor loops through the dataframe, fitting a model to each city

Problem:
The pipeline predicts wonderfully when I limit the dataframe to one city. Once I add a second city, only the last partition in the loop predicts fine. The cities that get fitted prior to the last city all report terrible r-squared values (and shoddy predicted values), even though the model predicts them well when processed individually. **I think the problem is I'm not initializing a new regression model at each partition.**

regressor (abbreviated)

```py
def regressor(btr_list, silly_amenities, numeric_cols, model='random_forest', one_model=False):
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, PolynomialFeatures

    zip_transformer = FunctionTransformer(zipcode_cleaner)
    ... # other function transformers

features = ColumnTransformer([
        ('zip transformer', Pipeline([
            ('fill gaps of Zip', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
            ('zipper', zip_transformer),
            ('ohe zip', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
        ]), ['Zip']),
        prem_unit # variable returning a tuple
        ... # other steps in the Column Transformer
    ])

    if model == 'random_forest':
        param_grid = {'max_depth': range(5, 300, 20), 'max_features': range(2, 20, 5), 'min_samples_leaf': range(1, 15)}
        gs = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100), param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, n_iter=20)
    elif model == 'ridge':
        param_grid_ridge = {'alpha': np.logspace(-3, 3, num=30)}
        gs = RandomizedSearchCV(Ridge(), param_grid_ridge, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, n_iter=20)
    else:
        print('Error. Model selected is not a defined model')
        return None

    est = Pipeline([
        ('features', features),
        ('scaling', scaler),
        ('regressor', gs)
    ])
    
    return est
```

stacking regressor

```py
    def fit(self, X, y):
        cnt = 0
        groups = X[self.grouper].unique()
        
        for subj in groups:
            cnt += 1
            print(f'{subj} ({cnt} of {len(groups)})')
            
            ind = (X[self.grouper]==subj) # bool index; assumes X and y are in same order (should be)
            X_subj = X[ind]
            y_subj = y[ind]
            
            self.estimators[subj] = self.estimator_factory()
            self.estimators[subj].fit(X_subj, y_subj)
            clear_output(wait=True)
            
        return self
```

I tried running it with one city in the dataframe. It worked well. I added a second city, the prediction of the original city deteriorated greatly. But if I re-shuffle the data, the second city predicts poorly. I checked the shuffle: whichever city is processed last, the prediction is fine. All cities that are not last have poor predictions.

It seems like the fitted models are getting trashed by subsequent loops, but I can't see how. I also check the metrics method to ensure that it isn't just reporting poor performance. However, the actual predictions are poor, so I don't think it is the metrics mis-reporting.

I'd expect to see the same performance of the model wether processed with one city or multiple cities.

Comment: What's the type of `X` here? It'll act differently depending on whether it's a NumPy array or Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Pandas dataframe split using sklearn test/train split. 'SubjectId' is the city I was referring to. `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, shuffle=True, stratify=X['SubjectId'])`

Answer (score 0):

After much travail, I found the error. As suspected, a new model was not being initialized on each partition. I solved it by replacing this

```py
reg = regressor(btr, silly_amenities, numeric_cols, one_model=False, model=model)
```

with this

```py
def regressor(): 
     # I would use a lambda here, but the named function can be pickled so I'll use this
     return regressor(btr, silly_amenities, numeric_cols, one_model=False, model=model)
```

I get the problem, but don't fully understand why the regressor function doesn't initialize a new model each time. Explanations and education is appreciated.